# JPQL check if collection member has attribute with required value

Tags: collections, jpql

I have entity (e.g. *Setting*) which contains collection (e.g. *Settings.languages*) with another objects (instances of *Language*).

Is there way how to select all entities which contains in its collection entity with required attribute value? e.g. get all *Setting*s which *Settings.languages* contains *Language.code* = 'EN' ?

Something like:

```
 SELECT s FROM Setting s WHERE :code MEMBER OF s.languages.code
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT s FROM Setting s INNER JOIN s.languages c WHERE c = :code
```

More examples was [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#FROM_Clause)

Comment: I hoped that there is less "SQL-like" (more "Java-like") way